# Bitfinex Api v2 [ 'error', 10112, 'signature: invalid' ]

Tags: javascript, cryptocurrency

I want to see my account bitcoin address via JavaScript, I use the following code, but it only displays:

> [ 'error', 10112, 'signature: invalid' ]

when run, I followed the code from the [source docs](https://docs.bitfinex.com/reference/rest-auth-deposit-address).

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js') // Standard JavaScript cryptography library
const fetch = require('node-fetch') // "Fetch" HTTP req library
   
const apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxx'
const apiSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxx'

const apiPath = 'v2/auth/w/deposit/address'// Example path

fetch(`https://api.bitfinex.com/${apiPath}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
      wallet: 'trading',
      method: 'bitcoin',
      op_renew: 0 // 1 for new address
    }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'bfx-apikey': apiKey
  }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => console.log(json))
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
 })
```

Comment: You must authenticate your API. Missing `bfx-signature` and `bfx-nonce` headers. https://docs.bitfinex.com/docs/rest-auth

Comment: could you spare some time how to add bfx-signature and bfx-nonce, thank you for your attention

Comment: Got to link, there click on JavaScript, you will find example of how to generate them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the error message "signature: invalid" suggests an issue with the authentication signature you are using. The Bitfinex API requires you to sign your request using your API key and secret.